# adding a button with jquery's insertAfter?

Tags: jquery

I have a button that I want to add after a div. If I declare the button inside the insertAfter call like this:

```
        $("<button class='cwButton' 
        onclick='btnClick()'>QUIZ!</button>").insertAfter("#contents-table");
```

It works, but I was wondering if I could declare the button in the html and add with the id like

```
 $("#cwButton").insertAfter("#contents-table");
```

but this way doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to do that or must it be declared in the function call?

Answer (score 0):

`cwButton` is a class, so use `.`, not `#`, which is for IDs.

```
$(".cwButton").insertAfter("#contents-table");
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ZjpUK/)**